# How to rename or move GCMIntentService

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I would like to put the GCMIntentService in a directory other than my package root.

The [GCM documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gs.html) states that

> ```
>       By default, it must be named .GCMIntentService, unless the
>       application uses a custom BroadcastReceiver that redefines its name.
> ```

My question is - how do I create this "custom BroadcastReceiver" thay talk about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this -- [Rename or change package of GCMIntentService class](http://dexxtr.com/post/28188228252/rename-or-change-package-of-gcmintentservice-class)

Answer (score 4):

The basic docs have you add the following to your manifest:

```
<receiver android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
    <category android:name="my_app_package" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

This points to a GCM-supplied `BroadcastReceiver` that will route events to your `.GCMIntentService`. If you wish to have your service reside in some other package, you will need to supply your own `BroadcastReceiver`. This may be as simple as creating one that subclasses `GCMBroadcastReceiver` and overrides `getGCMIntentServiceClassName()` to return the fully-qualified class name of the service to use.