# GCMService package name notation

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have started integrating GCM in my app. I have few queries regarding the package name in which GCMIntentService need to be put. As android.developer site states

```
By default, it must be named .GCMIntentService, unless the
application uses a custom BroadcastReceiver that redefines its name.
```

And my application was earlier using Service class, which was called `BackgroundService` which was in `com.abc.xyz.service` package. My root package name is `com.abc.xyz.ui.activity`. I have gone through [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13360219/how-to-rename-or-move-gcmintentservice) and [this one.](http://dexxtr.com/post/28188228252/rename-or-change-package-of-gcmintentservice-class) Solution works with there package name but with my package name its not same. as my root package is different.

My query is **Do I need to rename my package structure or there is some other way?** I don't want to rename the package name as its the standard format which we are using since beginning. So is there other way to do the same. Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

```
<receiver
            android:name="com.abc.xyz.service.GCMReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="com.abc.xyz.ui.activity" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name="com.abc.xyz.service.BackgroundService" />
```

**Update and complete ansewer**

As mentioned by Anup, it really does not matter where you put your file as far as you are qualifying it properly. Same did my job. You can take the ref. of [my other question link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14397202/onregistered-from-gcmintentservice-never-called) which helped me achieving the answer. [My this question link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14397202/onregistered-from-gcmintentservice-never-called) as every thing covered as it contains my manifest. So I am accepting Anup's answer as its not wrong atleast.

Comment: If you are using the library given in GCM sample application, you have to put this intent service class to parent package. For eg: `com.pckg.name` is parent folder then move service class to that package.

Comment: Thnx pankaj, My query is that one only. As my root package name is `com.abc.xyz.ui.activity` but service class is in `com.abc.xyz.service`. So apart from renaming my root package name, is there other alternative??

Comment: I don't think that if root package is `com.abc.xyz.ui.activity` then `com.abc.xyz.service` will be work. (I am not sure but) you should rename the package structure of your service class `com.abc.xyz.ui.activity.service` as I would say (And for readability this is not a good package structure for your service).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you qualify it properly in your manifest file declaration of the service, it really shouldn't matter AFAIK. You can put it in any package you want, just make sure you qualify it properly wherever you use it.

Comment: I have added small code detail `<category android:name="com.abc.xyz.ui.activity" />` this line will be address of root package or till my service package.Can u tell me that??

Comment: It should point to the package of the activity in which you are registering the broadcast receiver. If that activity is in `com.abc.xyz.ui.activity` then that's the one it should point to.

Comment: I am registering it MyApplication which extends Application. So package name for that MyApplication class should be given? This class is under package name `com.abc.xzy`.