# onRegistered() from GCMIntentService never called

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to register my app on GCM but I don't know why my app is never registered. `GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID);` is called but onRegistered() from my GCMIntentService is never called. I don't know **WHY**.

This is my Logcat

```
01-17 11:03:00.015: D/GCMRegistrar(3509): resetting backoff for com.abc.xyz.ui.activity
01-17 11:03:03.210: V/GCMRegistrar(3509): Registering app com.abc.xyz.ui.activity of senders 964256581311
01-17 11:03:06.070: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(3509): onReceive: com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION
01-17 11:03:06.070: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(3509): GCM IntentService class: com.abc.xyz.ui.activity.GCMIntentService
01-17 11:03:06.070: V/GCMBaseIntentService(3509): Acquiring wakelock
```

and this is my complete manifest

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest package="com.abc.xyz.ui.activity"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.5.6" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-sdk 
        android:minSdkVersion="11" android:targetSdkVersion="16"/>
    <uses-feature 
        android:name="android.hardware.usb.host"/>

    <!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <uses-permission 
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission 
        android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission 
        android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
    <uses-permission 
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission 
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission 
        android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" /> 
    <uses-permission 
        android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />

    <!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

    <!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" /> 

    <!--
     Creates a custom permission so only this app can receive its messages.

     NOTE: the permission *must* be called PACKAGE.permission.C2D_MESSAGE,
           where PACKAGE is the application's package name.
    -->
    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.abc.xyz.ui.activity.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />   
    <permission
        android:name="com.abc.xyz.ui.activity.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />    
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light" 
        android:name="com.abc.xyz.MyApplication" 
        android:allowBackup="false">
        <activity
            android:name=".StartupActivity"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:label="@string/title_startup_screen" 
            android:configChanges="orientation">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible|adjustResize"
            android:label="@string/title_login_screen"
            android:configChanges="orientation">
        </activity>
        //my other activity defination

        <!--
          BroadcastReceiver that will receive intents from GCM
          services and handle them to the custom IntentService.

          The com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND permission is necessary
          so only GCM services can send data messages for the app.
        -->
        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="com.abc.xyz.ui.activity" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!--
          Application-specific subclass of GCMBaseIntentService that will
          handle received messages.

          By default, it must be named .GCMIntentService, unless the
          application uses a custom BroadcastReceiver that redefines its name.
        -->
        <service android:name="com.abc.xyz.ui.activity.GCMIntentService" />

    </application>
</manifest>
```

I don't know what is wrong and why onRegistered() is never called. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How do you verify that it isn't called? Oh and which method are you talking about? Title says onRegistered, body says onReceived...

Comment: Sry, I will change. OnRegistered() is the method name. And i have put a log and Debug point both. And none is coming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answer because pasting code is barely readable in comments:

I am missing some logs from your logcat that suggest your service is even called. I have this in my Logcat when registering:

```
GCMBroadcastReceiver  V  onReceive: com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION
GCMBroadcastReceiver  V  GCM IntentService class: com.package.android.app.GCMIntentService
GCMBaseIntentService  V  Acquiring wakelock
GCMBaseIntentService  V  Intent service name: GCMIntentService-DynamicSenderIds-1
```

Especially the last line is missing or you have forgotten to paste it. Could you make sure that you posted the complete LogCat? Filter for `GCM` to make sure you didn't missed something.

**Update**

As the OP mentioned in the comments, he used the service to do more. This somehow interfered with the GCM functionality and after separating this into two services it worked. Lessons learned: Don't use the GCMIntentService for anything else than GCM.

Comment: No i have not missed out any thing relevant from logcat, its just that last line is never called in my case. Can you point out why its not getting called...

Comment: Your GCMIntentService is at package level (the one defined at the beginning of your manifest files)?

Comment: yup. same package as other activity and one defined in manifest tag ie com.abc.xyz.ui.activity

Comment: `<category android:name="com.abc.xyz.ui.activity" />` is `com.abc.xyz.ui.activity` you root package for the application?

Comment: I am curious why you have package `com.abc.xyz.ui.activity` in your manifest but `com.abc.xyz` as your application package. I am not sure if this cause any trouble. The GCMIntentService needs to be at a very specific place and normally you would use the root package but as your manifest package is a subpackage of your application package... well this is unusual.

Comment: ok let me move it to `com.abc.xyz.ui.activity` only. But I have already tried it and result was same. But still i will move it to corresponding package

Comment: Still same result. I have moved my MyApplication to `com.abc.xyz.ui.activity` package and update manifest. Still same logcat out and onRegistered() never called

Comment: Is there anything in the LogCat that might indicate that the Service wasn't successfully started? I am a bit lost here as I can't find any issues... have you checked if other methods of the service might be called?

Comment: Don't know exactly where things are going wrong. I am trying from past 2 weeks but still same thing same output.

Comment: GCMIntentService class is quite lengthy, as I have my service class implementation also. If you want I can paste code related to GCM only or u want me to paste entire code???

Comment: Could you strip it down somehow? Or use pastebin if it is still too long

Comment: I would separate both services. I am not sure if it is a good idea to interfere too much with the GCMIntentService.

Comment: ohh. k I will have to try. okk will come back to you once i implement two services in single app.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got it running. Two service class did the work

Comment: Great! I updated the answer to add a brief summary so that nobody needs to read through all the comments :)

Comment: What do you mean with "use the service to do more?" I have only the callbacks and the constructor and my onRegistered is never called too.

Comment: @RaphaelOliveira create a new question and post the manifest and the code where you call `GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID);`

Comment: @Android i have same problem but i don't get successful result pls help i can do every thing regarding this.

Answer (score 10):

I figured out in another post what is the problem. My GCMIntentService Class was defined in my manifest as

```
<service android:name="MY_PACKAGE.gcm.GCMIntentService" />
```

because I didn't want to put this class at the root package, instead I put at MY_PACKAGE.gcm". This seems to cause a problem and as the documentation says,

Add the following intent service

```
<service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />
```

So when I moved to the root package it worked! There is another way to put the GCMIntentServiceSubclass wherever you want and name it differently. You should subclass GCMBroadcastReceiver and do the changes in manifest and in the subclass as shown in this other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11332034/google-gcmintentservice-instantiate).

Comment: This was my issue.  After 3 hours of debugging it came down to the AndroidManifest!

Comment: Wow! .... that works. It's annoying that i can't put "gcmIntent" in "my_package" :(